# Codeception: No tests executed

Tags: yii2, codeception

```
$ ../vendor/bin/codecept run codeception/unit/models/MemberTest.php
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.0.16
Powered by PHPUnit 4.7.7 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

←[1mUnit Tests (0) ←[22m------------------------------
---------------------------------------------


Time: 2.99 seconds, Memory: 10.25Mb

←[30;43mNo tests executed!←[0m
```

I am getting [1m and 30;43m, but I have no idea what they mean, unless they're some debug output that are basically meaningless.

Not sure what's wrong. I mean if there's something that went wrong, they should be more explicit. Here's my MemberTest class:

```
<?php

namespace tests\codeception\unit\models;

use yii\codeception\TestCase;
use app\models\Member;

class MemberTest extends TestCase {

public function basicTest()
{
    $John = Member::findOne(['nickname'=>'John']);
    $this->assertNotNull($John);
}

public function fixtures()
{
    return [
    'members' => 'app\tests\codeception\fictures\MemberFixture'
    ];
}

}
```

I also made a fixture class, MemberFixture:

```
<?php 

namespace app\tests\codeception\fixtures;

use yii\test\ActiveFixture;

class MemberFixture extends ActiveFixture
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Member';
}
```

And a data class member:

```
<?php

return [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'firstName' => 'John',
        'lastName' => 'Bush',
        'email' => 'jb@hotmail.com',
        'username' => 'Warmonger',
        'password' => 'allo',
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'firstName' => 'Jane',
        'lastName' => 'Bush',
        'email' => 'jane@hotmail.com',
        'username' => 'PluckedFlower',
        'password' => 'allo',
    ],


];
```

I also ran codecept build after changing the unit.suite.yml file:

```
# Codeception Test Suite Configuration

# suite for unit (internal) tests.
# RUN `build` COMMAND AFTER ADDING/REMOVING MODULES.

class_name: UnitTester
modules:
   enabled:
    - Asserts
```

I have no idea what's wrong. I am using Yii2 in case you haven't figured it out yet. I changed the Member class and tested it out by inserting Member elements with the form and everything to make sure my models and controllers worked fine, so I am completely clueless here.

Comment: the `←[30;43m` and the like are shell colour codes, you appear to be using a terminal that does not support colours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test method was not executed, because it doesn't follow naming convention - the method name must begin with "test".

```
public function testBasic()
{
}
```

http://codeception.com/docs/05-UnitTests#Classical-Unit-Testing

Answer (score 0):

You should run single test with this command:

```
../vendor/bin/codecept run unit models/MemberTest
```

where `unit` it's suite name and `models/MemberTest` is path relative from `unit` suite folder.